# Filtering a 2D array/list and replacing a value in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 2d

I want to replace a number in this 2d array if the username already exists.

```
[["bob man", "0"], ["bill kill", "5"], ["nick", "5"]]
```

For example, when I receive the username "bob man", with the new number 44. I want to search my array and check if this username exists, and replace the number. If it doesn't exist, I want to append it to the array.

```
[["bob man", "44"], ["bill kill", "5"], ["nick", "5"]]
```

Is there a better way of storing this? I am new to python, and simple stuff like this seems much more complex than in js etc. Objects?

Comment: Instead of using list of lists(2d array) you can use dictionary to store data, because lookup's in dictionary are very fast compared to lists.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thanks! I knew there had to be much easier ways to do this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy structured array if you would like to keep the order:

```
a = np.array([("bob man", 0), ("bill kill", 5), ("nick", 5)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('value', 'i4')])
new_entry = np.array([('bob man', 44)], dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('value', 'i4')])

if new_entry['name'] in a['name']:
  a['value'][a['name']==new_entry['name']] = new_entry['value']
else:
  a = np.append(a, new_entry)
```

I expect it to be faster than dictionaries, specially if you want to add more than one entry, you can include them all in `new_entry` and change code a bit to check array-wise to be faster.